# ¿Cómo puedo usar variables shell en awk?

Tags: bash, awk

Estoy intentando escribir un script que filtre la información del comando `sar` y lo muestre en formato XML.

Para ello, se me ha ocurrido hacer un bucle que vaya mostrando los datos de cada CPU y, dentro de él, otro bucle que vaya recorriendo los campos filtrados en la variable `last_time`.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
#Obtenemos el numero de nucleos de la CPU
NUM_CPU=$(grep processor /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l)

#Por cada nucleo, mostramos sus estadísticas
for i in $(seq 0 1 $(($NUM_CPU-1))); do

    #Guardamos la última medida de sar en una variable
    last_time=$(sar -P $i | tail -n 2 | head -n 1)

    for j in $(seq 3 1 8); do

            #Filtramos el campo correspondiente
        cpu_user=$(echo $last_time | gawk '{print $j}')


        #Mostramos el valor en XML
            echo "<module>"
            echo "<name><![CDATA[SAR: CPU$i $cpu_user]]></name>"
            echo "<description>Muestra el % de tiempo de usuario de la cpu $i</description>"
            echo "<type><![CDATA[generic_data]]></type>"
            echo "<![CDATA[15,1]]>"
            echo "</module>"

        #Imprimimos una linea en blanco para separar la siguiente seccion
             echo ""

    done;
done;
```

La mayoría del código se ejecuta bien, pero al intentar aplicar gawk con la variable `$j` (que indicaria el número de campo a filtrar), gawk no me detecta el valor de la variable y no me filtra nada

¿Cómo puedo resolverlo?

Comment: ¿ Porqué usas **comillas dobles** en todo tu código, menos **justamente** donde dices que está el fallo ?

Comment: Con comillas dobles el resultado es el mismo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para usar variables de Bash en awk debes pasárselas usando `-v`:

```
awk -v columna="$j" '{print $columna}'
```

Si quieres usarla para hacer comparaciones a nivel expresión regular, debes usar el operador `~`:

```
awk -v columna="$j" '$0 ~ columna'
```

Por tanto, la línea:

```
cpu_user=$(echo $last_time | gawk '{print $j}')
```

Sería

```
cpu_user=$(echo $last_time | gawk -v col="$j" {print $col}')
```

---

Dicho lo cual, tu código podría escribirse como:

```
#Obtenemos el numero de nucleos de la CPU
#### Usa directamente `nproc`:  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/17089001/1983854
NUM_CPU=$(nproc --all)

#Por cada nucleo, mostramos sus estadísticas
#### Aquí se puede usar un bucle clásico
for ((i=0; i<$NUM_CPU; i++)); do

    #Guardamos la última medida de sar en una variable
    last_time="$(sar -P $i | tail -n 2 | head -n 1)"

    #### Entiendo que aquí el 8 debería ser $(($NUM_CPU))
    for j in $(seq 3 1 8); do

        #Filtramos el campo correspondiente
        cpu_user=$(echo $last_time | gawk '{print $j}')

        #Mostramos el valor en XML
        #### ¿Más limpio un heredoc?
            cat - <<EOF
<module>
<name><![CDATA[SAR: CPU$i $cpu_user]]></name>
<description>Muestra el % de tiempo de usuario de la cpu $i</description>
<type><![CDATA[generic_data]]></type>
<![CDATA[15,1]]>
</module>

EOF

    done
done
```

He encabezado las sugerencias con `####`. Básicamente, usa `nproc --all` para contar los cores y usa un heredoc en lugar de muchos `echo`s.

Comment: Muchas gracias por las aclaraciones. Al final he replanteado el problema poniendo la lista de campos dentro del for, pero he aplicado tus sugerencias para NUM_CPU y para la impresión de valores.