# Mediante un script awk, ¿cómo obtener todos los campos entre dos token en base a un argumento cualquiera de un campo determinado?

Tags: linux, script, shell, awk

Imaginemos que tengo un fichero con los siguientes campos, delimitados por el token $$$$:

```
$$$$

> <DATABASE_ID>
HMDB0000016

> <DATABASE_NAME>
hmdb

> <FORMULA>
C21H30O3

$$$$

 <DATABASE_ID>
HMDB0000017

> <DATABASE_NAME>
hmdb

> <FORMULA>
C8H9NO4

$$$$

> <DATABASE_ID>
HMDB0000020

> <DATABASE_NAME>
hmdb

> <FORMULA>
C8H8O3

$$$$
```

En este caso, me gustaría poder obtener todos los campos que están entre dos token cualesquiera mediante el valor del campo DATABASE_ID a través de un script awk. Por poner un ejemplo, supongamos que escojo el valor asociado a este campo `HMDB0000020`. ¿Cómo podría pasarle el valor de este campo al script awk para que me imprima por pantalla todos los campos que están entre los token?

Hasta el momento, he conseguido escribir un comando desde la línea de comandos que me imprima por pantalla lo que está entre ambos token. Este comando lo he conseguido gracias al post [https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/407481/83.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/407481/83)

Siguiendo con el ejemplo:

```
awk -v RS='\n\\$\\$\\$\\$\n' '/HMDB0000020/' fichero

> <DATABASE_ID>
HMDB0000020
> <DATABASE_NAME>
hmdb
> <FORMULA>
C8H8O3
```

Sin embargo, a mí me interesa poder llamar a un script mediante `awk -f -v variable=HMDB0000020` y que aparezca la misma salida, pero no sé cómo podría reescribir el comando que tengo.

¿Alguna idea?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres mover la lógica a un fichero de Awk, simplemente debes crear un nuevo archivo y, para mejor visibilidad, ponerle extensión `.awk`.

Por ejemplo, podemos crear "s.awk" con este contenido:

```
BEGIN{
    RS="\n\\$\\$\\$\\$\n"
}
$0 ~ var
```

Y lo ejecutamos de la siguiente manera:

```
awk -f s.awk -v var="HMDB0000020" fichero
```

Es decir, ejecutamos Awk a través del script `s.awk` y le pasamos la variable `var` mediante la sintaxis `-v nombre_variable="valor variable"`, tal y como comentábamos en [¿Cómo puedo usar variables shell en awk?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/110490/83). Finalmente, `fichero` es el contenido que usa para procesar.

En cuanto al contenido en sí del fichero, fíjate que he movido la lógica del RS al bloque BEGIN, que es la manera que tenemos de cambiar este valor sin pasarlo al llamar a Awk "en línea". Es decir, `awk -v RS="bla"` es lo mismo que `awk 'BEGIN{RS="bla"}` y nos permite ponerlo dentro del fichero.

Luego, la parte de `$0 ~ var` consiste en validar que la línea dada tenga el mismo patrón que le pasas mediante la variable "var".

Comment: Increíble explicación!! Me ha servido a la perfección. Muchas gracias!!! :D

Comment: Me alegra :) Los comentarios no resultaban suficientemente claros y aquí puede explicar con mayor detalle.